# For loop increment by a non-integer in TCL

Tags: tcl

I want to implement the following C code in TCL:

```
Float power_pitch = 8
float offset = 7.5
float threshold = 100 
for(i=power_pitch+offset ; i<= threshold ; i += power_pitch)
```

I want to implement above forloop in TCL. I have tried the following code in TCL:

```
set power_pitch 8
set offset 7.5
set threshold 100
for { set i [expr $power_pitch + $offset] } { $i <= $threshold } { incr i $power_pitch}
```

but when I execute above code I get the following error:

> expected integer but got "15.5 "
>   while executing incr i $power_pitch

Could you help me to implement above forloop in TCL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `incr` command only works with integers. Otherwise, use:

```
set i [expr {$i + $power_pitch}]
```

The `for` command itself won't mind. (Be aware of float rounding issues; they're not Tcl-specific, but can hit with anything that isn't an integer multiple of a power of 2…)

Answer (score 3):

Donal has already provided the answer to the question, I'd just like to make an observation in two points about the `for` command.

1. `for` is very nearly free-form
2. while an integral counting loop is a typical use of `for`, it's by no means the only option

The `for` command has the synopsis

**for** *start* *test* *next* *body*

where *start*, *next*, and *body* are command strings (i.e. appropriate as an argument to `eval`; they can be empty, contain single commands, or be full scripts) and *test* is a boolean expression string (i.e. appropriate as an argument to `expr` *and* evaluating to something that is or can be coerced into a boolean value).

Usually, *start* is used to set up for *test* and *body*, and *next* is supposed to bring the state incrementally closer to having *test* return a false value, but that's just a convention, not a requirement. The following are perfectly valid (but rather smelly) invocations:

```
for {set n 0 ; puts -nonewline X} {[incr n] < 5} {puts -nonewline X} {
    puts -nonewline [string repeat - $n]
}

for {set f [open foo.txt] ; set n 0} {$n >= 0} {puts $line} {
    set n [chan gets $f line]
}
```

Give `for` any combination of command strings and boolean expression, and it will run. It might execute its body forever or not even once, but it will run. Don't limit yourself to `for {set i 0} {$i < 10} {incr i} {...}` invocations, that's 1950s thinking.

Even if you just want to use it for counting loops, there are still lots of options, for instance:

```
for {set i 0} {$i < $limit} {incr i} {...}             ;# simple increment
for {set i 0} {$i < $limit} {incr i $n} {...}          ;# stepping increment/decrement
for {set i 0} {$i < $limit} {incr i $i} {...}          ;# doubling increment
for {set i 0} {$i < $limit} {set i [expr {...}]} {...} ;# arbitrary change
```

Free your mind, the rest will follow.

Documentation: [chan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/chan.htm), [expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm), [for](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/for.htm), [incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm), [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)